# Why do electrically charged fields necessarily interact with Higgs field?

Tags: electromagnetism, mass, higgs

There are no elementary charged particles without mass. Since elementary particles appear to acquire mass by the Higgs mechanism, the above statement seems to imply that any charged particle must necessarily interact with the Higgs field, although nothing in the basic Higgs proposal seems to suggest a relationship between electric charge and the Higgs field. Any additional ideas?

There are also other conceptual problems with the possibility of an electric charge being massless (although they do not seem to be related to the Higgs field): the electromagnetic field of charged particles moving at the speed of light would present problems from the perspective of relativity (consider [Liénard–Wiechert potentials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li%C3%A9nard%E2%80%93Wiechert_potential)). That implies that we would get into trouble if there were not a mechanism that provides a mass to charged particles. But, in reality, we conjecture that electrically charged fermions gain mass through their interaction with the Higgs field.

However, is it possible that the electrically charged particles are compelled by something to interact with the Higgs field, solving the issue of charges traveling at the speed of light? Has anyone put forth a mechanism or theory regarding it?

Comment: "There are no elementary charged particles without mass...  it is possible that the electrically charged particles are **compelled by something within them**..." What do you mean "within them"? Elementary particles are pointlike, they don't have a finite volume for anything to be "within." So, at least to me, it is not clear what this is supposed to mean.

Comment: "Has anyone put forth a mechanism or wild theory regarding it?" A "wild theory" seems like it is potentially outside of mainstream physics (so potentially off topic here).

Comment: It's a excellent question, and the reason is simply that if massless charged particles existed all uncharged particles would decay to them and we physicists wouldn't exist. The question I've linked goes into more details. @hft and Miyase I think you need to reconsider your close voting decisions.

Comment: @JohnRennie No.

Comment: I also think that it is a rather interesting question, but I am voting to leave this closed because the linked question correctly answers the essence of the question, even if the OP does not understand. We just need to explain that asserting that the Higgs must interact with the charged particles (false, but just to entertain) is the same thing as asserting that the charged particles must not be massless. The linked question correctly answers that gluons are massless charged particles and no stable massless charged particles are compatible with our universe, thus answering the essence.